# Simulating 3' end tag-based scRNA-seq reads

Tags: scrnaseq, transcriptome, simulated-data

Are there any tools that will simulate 3' end tag-based single-cell RNA-seq reads? For example, `Drop-seq`, `10X Chromium`, `CEL-seq`?

There are tools that simulate scRNA-seq gene count data (e.g. [Splatter](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-017-1305-0)), but I can't find anything that will simulate reads or even counts at the transcript level.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a couple options have become available:

**Minnow**: [article](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/35/14/i136/5529127?login=true) [code](https://github.com/COMBINE-lab/minnow)

**scReadSim**: [preprint](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2022.05.29.493924v1) [code](https://github.com/JSB-UCLA/scReadSim)